# GXT 3.x EditorGrid: choose cell editor type on a cell by cell basis

Tags: gxt

Is there anyway to define the editor type on a cell by cell basis in **GXT 3.0**?

I need to create a transposed table; the column become the row and the row is the column. That being the case, a column (from a normal table point of view) will have various editor type, whereby a row will have identical editor type.

I am trying to use following approach - It seems to be working fine, and allow to open up editors based on data type but when i click out; it doesn't close/hide editor.

I would really appreciate if someone can please point me in right direction.

```
final GridInlineEditing<MyModel> editing = new GridInlineEditing<MyModel>(mygrid){
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override public <O> Field<O> getEditor(ColumnConfig<MyModel, ?> columnConfig) {
        if(valueColumnName.equals(columnConfig.getHeader().asString())) {
                MyModel myModel = tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            if(MyModelType.STRING.equals(myModel.getMyModelType())) {
                TextField textField =  new TextField();
                textField.setAllowBlank(Boolean.FALSE);
                return (Field<O>) textField;
            }
            else {
                TextArea textField =  new TextArea();
                textField.setAllowBlank(Boolean.FALSE);
                return (Field<O>) textField;
            }
        }
        return super.getEditor(columnConfig);
    }
};
editing.setClicksToEdit(ClicksToEdit.TWO);
```

PS:
This is similar to question below; but answer is specific to post GXT 3.0. I am new to stackoverflow and it seems recommendation was to create new question instead of adding new post to old thread. 
[GXT EditorGrid: choose cell editor type on a cell by cell basis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6973189/gxt-editorgrid-choose-cell-editor-type-on-a-cell-by-cell-basis)

Answer (score 3):

After playing around all day; my colleague(Praveen) and I figured it out. So instead of trying to override GridInlineEditing's getEditor() method override startEditing() method. Also, you will need converters if you have data like Date, List etc. Below is sample code; hope this help others.

```
final GridInlineEditing<MyModel> editing = new GridInlineEditing<MyModel>(tree){
            @Override public void startEditing(GridCell cell) {
                MyModel myModel= tree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                if(MyModelType.TEXT.equals(myModel.getContextVariableType())) {
                    TextArea textField =  new TextArea();
                    textField.setAllowBlank(Boolean.FALSE);
                    super.addEditor(valueColumn, textField);
                }
                else if(MyModelType.BOOLEAN.equals(myModel.getContextVariableType())) {
                    SimpleComboBox<String> simpleComboBox = new SimpleComboBox<String>(new StringLabelProvider<String>());
                    simpleComboBox.setTriggerAction(TriggerAction.ALL);
                    simpleComboBox.add("YES");
                    simpleComboBox.add("NO");
                    super.addEditor(valueColumn, simpleComboBox);
                }
                else if(MyModel.INTEGER.equals(myModel.getContextVariableType())) {
                    SpinnerField<Integer> spinnerField = new SpinnerField<Integer>(new IntegerPropertyEditor());
                    spinnerField.setIncrement(1);
                    Converter<String, Integer> converter = new Converter<String, Integer>(){
                        @Override public String convertFieldValue(Integer object) {
                            String value = "";
                            if(object != null) {
                                value = object.toString();
                            }
                            return value;
                        }
                        @Override public Integer convertModelValue(String object) {
                            Integer value = 0;
                            if(object != null && object.trim().length() > 0) {
                                value = Integer.parseInt(object);
                            }
                            return value;
                        }
                    };
                    super.addEditor(valueColumn, converter, (Field)spinnerField);
                }
                else {
                    TextField textField =  new TextField();
                    textField.setAllowBlank(Boolean.FALSE);
                    super.addEditor(valueColumn, textField);
                }
                super.startEditing(cell);
            }
        };
        editing.setClicksToEdit(ClicksToEdit.TWO);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are not seeing the fields not closing is because you are not actually adding them to the GridInlineEditing class.

In the parts where you have the following return statements;

```
return (Field<O>) textField;
```

Those textfields are never added to the grid.

I would try substituting the following code for your first two return statement;

```
super.addEditor(columnConfig, (Field<O>) textField;
```

This adds the editor to some maps used by `AbstractGridEditing`. Specifically, the `AbstractGridEditing.removeEditor(GridCell, Field<?>)` method, which is used in `GridInlineEditing.doCompleteEditing()` and `GridInlineEditing.cancelEditing()` needs the field to be in the map so it can be detached from its parent.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I tried but no luck; behavior is still same. 
Also, removeEditor() is a private method; So i tried implementing my own with same logic and calling it explicitly but that didn't help either.

Comment: So you added code to set their parents to null and detach from DOM, but they are still there? That doesn't sound right.

Comment: Yes; it's strange. Anyways, we figured it out. And hey! thanks for pointing us to "super.addEditor(columnConfig, (Field<O>) textField;". This was helpful :) Thanks again.

Comment: Well you should make an answer to your question then ;)