# Making a Grid cell editable based on ModelData in GXT 3.0.1

Tags: grid, cell, gxt, custom-cell

I want to make a Grid Cell editable based on the data in that cell.

The cell accepts a String. so, i am adding a Text editor as follow:

```
 final GridInlineEditing<ModelData> editableGrid = new GridInlineEditing<ModelData>(grid);

    int columnCount = grid.getColumnModel().getColumnCount();
   final TextField text = new TextField();
    for(int i=1;i<columnCount-1;i++)
    {
        final ColumnConfig<ModelData,String> config = grid.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);        
          editableGrid.addEditor(config, text);
    }
```

and also.when i was creating the grid

```
config.setCell(new AbstractCell<String>() {


           @Override
           public void render(Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb)
           {
               ModelData model  = getGrid().getStore().get(context.getIndex());
               if(null==value)
               {
                   value = "";
               }
               if(model.getName().equals("vivek") {
                   sb.appendHtmlConstant("<div style=\"background-color:#E9967A;\">");
                   sb.appendHtmlConstant((String)value);
                   sb.appendHtmlConstant("</div>");

                 }
                else{

                     sb.appendHtmlConstant("<span>" + value + "</span>");            
                }
           }


   });
```

But, i could not make the required field editable( I am able to make them colored).
getGrid(), is a method that simply returns the grid

Then, i tried with setting editor to TextField with Custom TextInputCell, but this does not accepts HTML.

So, how can i achieve this. Making a Grid cell editable, based on the data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070953/gxt-3-x-editorgrid-choose-cell-editor-type-on-a-cell-by-cell-basis

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632458/how-to-add-css-to-selected-row-in-treegrid-gxt-3

These 2 discussed the same problem, but i could not figure out making editable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found answer myself :)

```
editableGrid.addBeforeStartEditHandler(new BeforeStartEditHandler<ModelData>() {

@Override
public void onBeforeStartEdit(BeforeStartEditEvent<ModelData> event) {    
    ModelData data = grid.getStore().get(event.getEditCell().getRow());

    if(condition)
    event.getSource().getEditor(event.getSource().getEditableGrid().getColumnModel().getColumn(event.getEditCell().getCol())).enable();
            }
    else {
     event.getSource().getEditor(event.getSource().getEditableGrid().getColumnModel().getColumn(event.getEditCell().getCol())).disable();
        }
}
```

Comment: Please comment if find any issue with the approach

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue. http://stackoverflow.com/q/22610705/1903120 can you please give the solution for that please

Comment: I have not worked with GXT 2. Ask for help in Sencha forum. sencha.com/forum

Comment: I am using GXT 2.2.3 now.Can you please how to move to GXT 3.0.to solve this issue.